# Find shortest text containing all combinations of a given string

Tags: java, algorithm

Given a string, find another string which contains all the combinations of the input string.

**Example**:

If input string = "23", then its combinations would be ["22", "23", "32", "33"],

One of the strings to contain all the above combinations would be "22233233", but that would not be the shortest. The shortest would be "22332".

Algorithm should be generic enough to work for input string of any size. (Assume that input is not too large and the output will remain under normal int/string/jvm etc. sizes. Also assume that input string will have alphanumeric characters from English language only)

I have tried the following algorithm but it does not seem to be working:

1) Find all combinations of the string = ["22", "23", "32", "33"]

2) Build a prefix map [2: {22, 23}, 3: {32, 33}]

3) Start from any combination and lookup suffix in the prefix map.

Example: Start with 22, its suffix is 2
From the prefix-map, values corresponding 2 are 22 and 23.
Pick one of the words here which is not the current picked word, so it will give 23

4) Add picked word's suffix to current string (This gives 223)

5) Repeat.
So I will get 223's suffix = 3
From prefix map, 3: {32, 33}
Choose any one, say 32
Append to current string to get 2232

6) If nothing else matches, append to current string. This gives 223233

However, the answer should be 22332 as that is the shortest.

Here is the full code I have written till now:

```
public class TextContainingAllPermutations
{
    static String input = "ABC";

    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        int suffixLen = input.length()-1;
        Set<String> combinations = getCombinations();
        while (suffixLen > 0 && combinations.size() > 1)
        {
            Map<String, List<String>> suffixToWords = getPrefixMap(combinations, suffixLen);
            String someWordsString = combinations.iterator().next();
            combinations.remove(someWordsString);
            Set<String> combinations2 = new HashSet<String>();

            while (combinations.size() > 0)
            {
                String suffix = someWordsString.substring(someWordsString.length()-suffixLen);
                List<String> words = suffixToWords.get(suffix);
                if (words == null || words.size()==0)
                {
                    combinations2.add(someWordsString);
                    System.out.println (someWordsString);
                    if (combinations.size() == 0)
                        break;
                    someWordsString = combinations.iterator().next();
                    combinations.remove(someWordsString);
                }
                else
                {
                    String w = words.get(words.size()-1);
                    words.remove(words.size()-1);
                    combinations.remove(w);
                    if (someWordsString.indexOf(w) == -1)
                        someWordsString += w.charAt(w.length()-1); // append last char
                }
            }
            combinations2.add(someWordsString);
            System.out.println (someWordsString);
            combinations = combinations2;
            suffixLen--;
        }
    }

    private static Map<String, List<String>> getPrefixMap(Set<String> combinations, int suffixLen)
    {
        Map<String, List<String>> suffixToWords = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
        for (String s: combinations)
        {
            String suffix = s.substring(0,suffixLen);
            if (!suffixToWords.containsKey(suffix))
            {
                suffixToWords.put(suffix, new ArrayList<String>());
            }
            suffixToWords.get(suffix).add(s);
        }
        return suffixToWords;
    }

    static Set<String> getCombinations()
    {
        char[] inputChars = input.toCharArray();
        int N = (int)Math.pow(input.length(), input.length());
        Set<String> combinations = new HashSet<String>(N);
        for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
        {
            char[] binary = padZeroes(Integer.toString(i, input.length())).toCharArray();

            String combination = "";
            for (int j=0; j<inputChars.length; j++)
            {
                char c = binary[j];
                int index = c - '0';
                char inputChar = inputChars[index];
                combination = inputChar + combination;
            }

            System.out.println (new String(binary) + " = " + combination);
            combinations.add(combination);
        }
        return combinations;
    }

    private static String padZeroes(String s)
    {
        int j = input.length()-s.length();
        for (int i=0; i<j; i++)
            s = '0' + s;
        return s;
    }
}
```

This is not a homework problem.

Comment: What have you determined will or will not work?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because its a "give me the code" question. You should probably [Take the Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: It may not be a homework problem, I'm willing to give you the benefit of the doubt  But...there's no sign of effort on your end, so it's going to be tough to convince us otherwise.

Comment: @Makoto, I have updated my algorithm here. I can put the full code also here to show attempt on my part.

Comment: That'd definitely help your cause.  It'd also help to mention why you don't think it's working, as "it's not working" isn't really a good description of a problem.  As loathe as I am to admit it, I've used it once or twice at work, but adding more information to the problem usually gave a satisfactory answer.

Comment: Hint:  This is secretly an Euler path problem.  (But there are a few screwy cases to handle.)

Comment: @tmyklebu: Yes, indeed, and the Wikipedia page referenced mentions that.

Answer (score 6):

What you are looking for is basically a [De Bruijn sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_sequence). A De Bruijn sequence `B(k,n)` is a cyclic sequence which contains all the possible subsequences of length `n` from a set of `k` symbols, each appearing exactly once. The length of the sequence is precisely `kn`.

The minimal non-cyclic sequence can be obtained by breaking the cycle at any point and then copying the first `n-1` symbols to the end, producing a sequence of length `kn + n - 1`, which is obviously minimal.

There are a variety of techniques to generate a De Bruijn sequence. The simplest technique to describe is that the de Bruijn sequence consists of the concatenation of all the [Lyndon words](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyndon_word) over the alphabet whose length divides `n`, in lexicographic order. (A Lyndon word is a sequence which is lexicographically previous to any rotation of itself. This implies that the Lyndon word is aperiodic.)

There is a simple algorithm to generate Lyndon words of maximum length `n` over an alphabet in lexicographic order:

1. Start with the length  consisting of only the lexicographically first character in the set.
2. As long as possible, form the next word by cyclically repeating the previous word up to length `n` (discarding the extra symbols from the last repetition, if necessary) and then "incrementing" the word by:

   1. As long as the last symbol in the word is the lexicographically greatest symbol in the alphabet, remove it.
   2. If there is still a symbol in the word, change the last symbol to the lexicographical successor. If there are no symbols left in the word, the production is finished.

To make the De Bruijn sequence of order `n`, we produce the above sequence of Lyndon words, but we only keep the ones whose length divides `n`. Since "almost all" of the Lyndon words of maximum length `n` are actually of length `n`, the algorithm can be considered O(1) per symbol, or `O(kn)` for the full sequence.

In the specific case requested by the question, `k == n`.